# Phone doesn't ring or show a popup for incoming calls

Tags: calls

My phone doesn't ring or show the on-screen popup when I receive calls. On incoming calls notification settings, it shows "~1 notification per day," so this may be related.

When I switch the preferred network type from LTE to 2G or vice versa, it rings and shows a popup only for the first call. When I make the second test call, it no longer rings or shows the popup until I change the preferred network type.

What may be the cause of this issue, and how to fix it? Is there any way I can increase the frequency of "~1 notification per day" or even unlimited?

Settings:

- Mobile data: On
- Do not disturb: Off
- Airplane mode: Off
- SIM status > Mobile network state: Connected

Incoming calls notifications:

- Pop on screen: On
- Sound: Chosen
- Show notification dot: On

- It shows "~1 notification per day"

What I've done:

- Reset network settings
- Re-inserted the sim card
- Restarted the phone

APN settings:

- Tried different settings as suggested by my phone provider

Note:

- This phone is supported by my phone provider
- The same SIM is working fine on another Android phone

Thank you.

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode too? If it does then it's a hardware  issue likely//If it doesn't, then an installed app could be the culprit but I don't think it's the case//You can take a backup of your important data and do a factory-reset to see if it helps. If you don't want to do that you can try automation to alert you when you get calls

Comment: Before checking in safe mode, try installing a phone app from Play Store to role out issues with phone app being used now

Comment: Thank you, beesyhams. Reinstalling the Phone app didn't fix the issue. It still occurs in safe mode, so it's like a hardware issue. But safe mode helped troubleshoot. I turned on notifications on system apps like Phone Services and Call Management. After that, it works when I set the preferred network type to 2G, but it's unstable with LTE though the phone supports LTE. I hope to avoid doing factory reset.

Comment: My phone company says the device is locked, while the seller says it's not locked. Does it make any sense that the phone lock may cause this issue? I suspect more of a hardware issue.

Comment: To me it looks like hardware issue. If you take it for repair, they will do a factory-reset. So you may as well do that and if it is fixed, you save the cost and time of repair

Comment: That makes sense. Suppose I run a factory reset, and the phone works fine. In that case, if I restore all apps and settings, is it possible to reproduce the issue?

Comment: If you restore apps one by one and check as you go along, you may be able to identify the culprit